# Depth-first-search in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hierarchy, depth-first-search

I have a snowflake database with the following table with columns `PARENT_ID`, `ITEM_ID`, `ORDER`. This table reflects the content of a file system, in which an item is a file or a folder and  the  `PARENT_ID` is the parent item of each item. The `order` is the position of each item inside its parent. For example this tree shows the hierarchy between items and the table after that shows the relations:

[image: starting table]

My objective is to retrieve the items id in a specific order based on depth first search. It means a table like that:

[resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOO6c.png)

Snowflake does not support the command `SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY ID SET DFS`. I think it can work leveraging the information level, position, parent position but until now I haven't been able to find a solution.

Otherwise there is something else I've tried to do: via API I've managed to get the final ordering of the items, so I have this information: an array of item_id, ordering. I don't know how to pass this information in the query that retrieves the final table.

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about performance here, but you can build the path of each item (based on depth and order) in a recursive CTE, and then sorting on that path will give you a depth first search.

```
with cte as (
    select parent_id, item, 0 as depth, [depth||','||ord] arr
    from mytable x
    where parent_id is null
union all
    select x.parent_id, x.item, c.depth+1, array_append(c.arr, c.depth+1||','||x.ord)
    from cte c 
    join mytable x
        on c.item = x.parent_id
)

select item
from cte
order by arr
```